# Multiple screen presentation Keynote

Tags: mac, keynote

I need to realize a presentation with this approach:

[image]

I want to realize different slide for screen 1 and 2 (or one single slide that fill correctly each screen with different contents). The content or slide scrolling must be synchronized in screen 1 and 2, so if i move one slide right screen 1 and 2 have to move one slide right togheter... I have read about multiscreen support in keynote ,but all i have read seems to limit this support to 2 screen the "laptop source screen" and an external screen, it possible to make a presentation like this in keynote?

Comment: You could always make your presentation into a responsive website :). I don't think Keynote can do this.

Comment: ok thanks,if there will be no more answers i'll sign this as correct